# Empty Data in ReportViewer in Local mode in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am trying to show some data in form of report in Windows Form application. I am using ReportViewer in local mode for that purpose. When i run the report, it shows empty report, no errors at all!! Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String thisConnectionString = "Data Source=AZEEM-NAWAZ;Initial Catalog=IEPL_Attendance_DB;Trusted_Connection = true;";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSetProducts.ShowProductByCategory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        //this.ShowProductByCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSetProducts.ShowProductByCategory);

        //this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        //reportViewer1.Visible = false;
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(thisConnectionString);
        System.Data.DataSet thisDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        string cmdText = "USE [IEPL_Attendance_DB] EXEC [ShowProductByCategory]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, thisConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter data_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        data_ad.Fill(thisDataSet);

        /* Associate thisDataSet  (now loaded with the stored 
       procedure result) with the  ReportViewer datasource */
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetProducts_DataSet1", thisDataSet.Tables[0]);

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        if (thisDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no products under this category!");
        }

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        //MessageBox.Show("Total Rows are: " + thisDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].ToString());
    }

    private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here are report.rdlc properties:
[image]

StoredProcedure "ShowProductByCategory" is returning data and i have verified by displaying rows count via MessageBox!!!

Answer (score 0):

`ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetProducts_DataSet1", thisDataSet.Tables[0]);`
In the above line remove the **"DataSetProducts_"** build it and try you will be able to see the data